# Can't change the title of the endnote section

Tags: captions, footnotes, endnotes, enotez

I'm using the `enotez` package in order to put my footnotes at the end of my documents.

When setting the document langage to French, the notes section's name change to “Remarques”, and I would like to change that back to “Notes”.

However, none of the techniques I've found online are useful.

I've first tried to use the command `\addto\captionsfrench{\def\notesname{Notes}}`, which does nothing; and the command `\renewcommand{\notesname}{Notes}` which only throw the error `Command \notesname undefined. \renewcommand{\notesname}`.

Here is the sample code to reproduce my problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{enotez}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\notesname{Notes}}
%\renewcommand{\notesname}{Notes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Test book}
\author{Someone}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}
    \sloppy
    \maketitle
    
    \chapter{First chapter}
    \lipsum[1-100]
    \endnote{\lipsum}
    
    \backmatter
    \printendnotes
    \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were not the author of `enotez` I'd probably look into the manual. I would then find this:

[image]

There is not much more to say:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{list-name=My cool title}

\newcommand\cs[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}
\newcommand\marg[1]{\texttt{\{#1\}}}

\begin{document}

Text\endnote{The title has been set through an option in \cs{setenotez},
  specifically with \cs{setenotez}\marg{list-name=My cool title}.}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]